# Passing parameter to web component to use in class fails

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, font-awesome

I have the following code in a [polymer](/questions/tagged/polymer) element that works fine:

```
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

However, I want to change the [font-awesome](/questions/tagged/font-awesome) icon based on a parameter.  So I changed that line to this:

```
<i class="fa fa-{{icon}}"></i>
```

And then I added the following property to the Polymer element:

```
icon: {
    type: String,
    value: 'user'
}
```

Running it as is, without even trying to pass a different value and just letting it use the default `'user'`, it doesn't render properly.  The DOM just has this:

```
<i class="style-scope widget-iconblock"></i>
```

I've tried a few other things, including replacing the entire `<i>` tag with `{{i}}` then having that return a calculated value similar to `"<i class='fa fa-" + self.icon + "'></i>"` but that rendered the literal text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding properties to native attributes requires [Polymer's attribute-binding syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#native-binding) (i.e., `class$="{{prop}}"`):

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <i class$="fa fa-{{icon}}"></i>
    </template>
    <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        properties : {
          icon: {
            type: String,
            value: 'user'
          }
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, one little `$` fixed the issue.  Thanks for the answer and the link to the relevant docs!

Comment: @Scott No problem

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding the following code to the `Polymer` `ready()` function:

```
$('#myelement').append("<i class='fa fa-" + self.icon + "'></i>");
```

I'd still love to see other/better answers.